Raising the dimensionless number to power, gave the dimension in the units while using pint registry in python
While I was using the pint registry in python as:

import pint
pq = pint.UnitRegistry()

density_water = (1 / 1.002)* 1e3 * pq.kg / pq.m**3
dynamic_viscocity_water = 959e-6 * pq.N * pq.s / pq.m**2
tube_inner_diameter = 2e-3 * pq.m
Prandtl_number = 6.62  # Dimensionless
mean_velocity_water  = 1 * pq.m / pq.s

# Reynolds number:
Reynolds_number = (density_water * mean_velocity_water * tube_inner_diameter) /dynamic_viscocity_water
print(np.mean(Reynolds_number.to_base_units()))

# Dittus-Boelter equation:
Nusselt_number = 0.0265 * (Reynolds_number) * (Prandtl_number)  # For cooling
print(np.mean(Nusselt_number.to_base_units()))


This code gives me dimensionless for both Reynolds and Nusselt numbers.
However, doing this gives me dimension (meter ** 2.22045e-16 / second ** 2.22045e-16) for the Nusselt_number, where it should have been dimensionless too.
Nusselt_number = 0.0265 * (Reynolds_number**0.8) * (Prandtl_number**0.3)  # For cooling
print(np.mean(Nusselt_number.to_base_units()))

I tried everything but it did not work. What could be wrong or is it built-in fault of Pint?

I can't reproduce your error - both alternative pieces of code correctly give dimensionless numbers. Try upgrading pint. (Incidentally, though, why do you need np.mean(); its parameters aren't an array.)
